# Multi-insert statement in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am coming across a problem with multi-insert in Hive

```
FROM staged_employees se
INSERT INTO TABLE us_employees
    AS SELECT * WHERE se.cnty = 'US'
INSERT INTO TABLE ca_employees
    AS SELECT * WHERE se.cnty = 'CA'
...
```

As far as I know, the multi-inserts are not IF ... ELSE ... construct, however, is it possible to make it into IF ... ELSE ... construct?

Answer (score 1):

HQL has no support for conditional logic. A literal answer to your question about splitting apart the insert is:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE us_employees
SELECT * 
FROM staged_employees se
WHERE se.cnty = 'US'

INSERT INTO TABLE ca_employees
SELECT *
FROM staged_employees se
WHERE se.cnty = 'CA'
```

All you will accomplish by splitting out your queries is reading all of the data from the `staged_employees` table twice. And, potentially, making other users of your cluster incredibly annoyed.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea for this particular problem (not generalizable). Create a partition by `cnty` on the output table, and create two external tables to the paths of the partitions:

```
CREATE TABLE all_employees (
  ...
)
PARTITIONED BY (cnty string)
...
LOCATION '/...../all_employees;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE us_employees (
  ...
)
LOCATION '/...../all_employess/US/';

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ca_employees (
  ...
)
LOCATION '/...../all_employess/CA/';
```

And then you just do the insert:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE all_employees PARTITION(cnty)
  SELECT * 
  FROM staged_employees se
  WHERE cnty in ('US','CA')
```

Answer (score 0):

despite been an old question the below image might help from the book **Programming Hive** by **Edward Capriolo, Dean Wampler and Jason Rutherglen** chapter 5 page 76

a snippet of hive command for writing multiple insert statements

[image]

substitute `OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/'tmp/or_employees` in above image with `INTO TABLE us_employees`

Best Regards

Answer (score -1):

IF...ELSE ...construct，OK，you can use CASE WHEN to do it.
Your code above is equal to this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE us_employees
SELECT * 
FROM staged_employees se
WHERE cnty in ('US','CA')
```

Comment: It is not equivalent. The goal is to insert into two different tables (us_employees and ca_employees).